# How to solve com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.Spacer class not found exception in Eclipse java swing projects

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, intellij-idea

I developed a Java Swing project in Intellij Idea, now have to convert that to Eclipse. I imported the project in Eclipse and then converted the form using 'Convert to JFormDesigner form'. While running the application getting the below mentioned exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.Spacer
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 31 more
```

I added forms_rt-6.0.5.jar and its dependencies to Lib, but still getting the same exception. Any idea how to solve this.. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Stop using com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.Spacer?

Comment: @Meo Issue got solved. Added that forms_rt.jar into the class path via manifest.mf, thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Issue got solved. Added that forms_rt.jar into the class path via manifest.mf file.